# Does the Michelson-Morley experiment disprove gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, gravitational-waves

I may be misunderstanding [gravitational waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave), but doesn't the idea of a gravitational wave imply that spacetime is a field or "medium" through which waves propagate at speed $c$? Was not this idea something disproven by the Michelson-Morley experiment, which discredits the idea that spacetime itself could be a frame of reference? Or would gravitational waves travel more like electromagnetic waves and are consistent in every reference frame thanks to Lorentz transformations?

I guess part of what I'm asking is, from the perspective of gravitational waves, if a massive object is moving through space at a high speed, then is there a gravitational-wave "doppler effect" (thanks to the limit of $c$) or does the gravitational wave propagate in all directions at the same speed relative to the position of the moving object?

Comment: No. Like electromagnetic waves, gravitational waves do not require a medium to travel through.

Comment: @prahar See edited question for clarification of what I'm asking.

Comment: The same light cones that describe light rays describe gravitational rays.

Comment: Assuming gravitational waves exist, so far they haven't been detected, they will propagate at the same speed in all directions. Unless GR is wrong there is no more gravitational ether wind than electromagnetic one. "Spacetime itself" is not a physical entity, especially in GR, which is covariant under any changes of coordinates, and certainly not a medium for any waves. Neither is "field", which is just a distribution of intensities. Early examples of waves were mechanical and spread in a medium, but that does not mean that all waves have to be mechanical and spread in a medium.

Comment: @Conifold - What do you mean the same speed in all directions? Do you mean relative to the moving object thanks to relativity? Or like a doppler effect (which is disproved by the Michelson-Morley experiment)? I'm assuming the former. But if the former is how it works, then would that mean the waves in front of the moving mass are traveling faster than $c$ and the waves behind traveling slower?

Comment: Relative to anything. Under relativistic addition c added to anything is c. As long as the "waves" carry energy they will be moving through vacuum at c relative to any observer and each other. They are physically incapable of moving at any speed other than c, Doppler effect affects frequency, but not speed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect You might be implicitly thinking of the classical rule for adding velocities instead of the relativistic one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Galilean_relativity

Comment: Got it, and so in that sense, the experiment does not disprove gravitational waves because of the relativistic addition of velocities instead of the classical addition. So despite the fact that we haven't really detected any with surety, gravitational waves are then still a possibility.

Comment: Correct. There is indirect evidence of gravitational waves  and people are actively looking. Unfortunately, they are very weak and hard to detect directly.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For practical purposes, gravitational waves travel in the same ways as light waves, and definitely at the same speed --- $c$.  Like with light, there is no preferred reference frame - so all observers will agree that they are moving at the speed of light (in all directions).

Regarding the Michelson-Morley experiment: the idea that this disproved a *'medium through which waves propagate'*, is (now) more of a philosophical point than a physical one.  What these experiments demonstrated, is that *there is no preferred reference frame* for light, or more generally, things traveling at the speed of light.